# How to get rolling sum for last 3 results where key value is either in one or another column in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

my table looks like this:

| Home team | Away team | Home index | Away index | home rolling score | away rolling score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Philadelphia | Atlanta | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| New York | Houston | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Denver | Orlando | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Philadelphia | Atlanta | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| New York | Houston | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Los Angeles | Atlanta | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Philadelphia | Atlanta | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| New York | Philadelphia | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| San Antonio | Dallas | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Philadelphia | Atlanta | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| New York | Philadelphia | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| Miami | Boston | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Philadelphia | Atlanta | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| New York | Houston | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I would like to get a rolling sum for last 3 results for Philadelphia for example for all of their matches, so if they played at home then the home index number should count, if they played away, away index should count.

The result should come in another column where the home team has calculated their rolling sum and also do the same for away team until that row (not including that row). This means in every row the query will look for a home team and calculate the rolling sum until that row.
So as in the example you can see home rolling score and away rolling score. If you check the Philadelphia score, it's 0 in the first row because there are no records before then in the next game of Philadelphia it's 1 because that's the sum of their previous games and in row 10  where there is game Philadelphia vs Atlanta, the rolling sum for home is 3 which is the sum of last 3 rows for Philadelphia without counting that row.

Any help how can I achieve this is much appreciated.

Comment: can you share example of desired  result?

Comment: In another column I would need to vlookup the home team and calculate their rolling sum and also do the same for away team until that row (not including that row). This means in every row the query will look for a home team and calculate the rolling sum until that row.

Comment: Manually add your desired results in new column(s) in the table you show in the question.

Comment: I added the columns and score for Philadelphia and edited the description

Comment: @Jerry I have created a formula for this, but it is not lining up with the desired result that you have provided. For example, in the last Philadelphia vs Atlanta row, you have the home rolling sum as 1, whereas the true rolling sum (of all the games) would be 4 up to that point, with the last three games being a sum of 3. Which of these numbers is the true desired result?

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 thanks and sorry, my table in the end is not correct anymore, I forgot to update the table until the end so your number is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

[image: ex]

```js
=sum(query(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("A"&row())),), "select * offset "&if(counta(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("A"&row())),))>3, counta(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("A"&row())),))-3, 0)))
```

```js
=sum(query(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("B"&row())),), "select * offset "&if(counta(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("B"&row())),))>3, counta(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("B"&row())),))-3, 0)))
```

The formulas are placed in cells `G2` and `H2` respectively, and are copied down the column. I was unable to get these to work as an array formula for the entire columns, but it may be possible.

I separated them so they could be better understood, but you could also combine them like this

```js
={sum(query(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("A"&row())),), "select * offset "&if(counta(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("A"&row())),))>3, counta(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("A"&row())),))-3, 0))),sum(query(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("B"&row())),), "select * offset "&if(counta(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("B"&row())),))>3, counta(ifna(filter(flatten(indirect("C1:D"&row()-1)), flatten(indirect("A1:B"&row()-1))=indirect("B"&row())),))-3, 0)))}
```

Placing this formula into cell `G2` and copying it down the column (autofilling `H`).

This formula finds the rolling score for the last 3 games of a given team.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot. I was killing myself with vlookup and stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

overal:

```
=QUERY(FILTER({FLATTEN(A2:B20), FLATTEN(C2:D20)}, 
 COUNTIFS(FLATTEN(A2:B20), FLATTEN(A2:B20), 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A20)*2), ">="&SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A20)*2))<4), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2>0 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", )
```

[image]

pivoted:

```
=QUERY(FILTER({FLATTEN(A2:B20), FLATTEN(C2:D20), 
 FLATTEN({"Home", "Away"}&IFERROR(ROW(A2:A20)/0))}, 
 COUNTIFS(FLATTEN(A2:B20), FLATTEN(A2:B20), 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A20)*2), ">="&SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A20)*2))<4), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2>0 group by Col1 pivot Col3", )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I need a different result. In another column I would need to vlookup the home team and calculate their rolling sum and also do the same for away team until that row (not including that row). This means in every row the query will look for a home team and calculate the rolling sum until that row.